# VBA: Getting run-time error '13' for no explicable reason

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub HighlightAndHalve()
    'This sub will highlight the cells which are above the threshold and also, halve the reductions based on this same condition
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, A As Range, LastRow As Long

    Set Sa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Data")
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sheets("Sales Output").Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In rng
        Set P = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        Set O = cell.Offset(0, -2)
        Set N = cell.Offset(0, -3)
        If cell.Value > 3 Then
            P.Value = P.Value / 2
            P.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            O.Value = (N.Value + P.Value)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Basically, in column Q I have a list of watchers for each product (collectible sneakers). If they have more than 3 watchers, then the reduction (column P) gets halved. O is the new price, N the original. So, in cases where the watcher count is above 3, then I want to add N to P.

No idea why I'm getting errors. All of the cells are set as general.

Comment: Where do you get that type mismatch error exactly?

Comment: O.Value = (N.Value + P.Value)

Comment: `LastRow` is calculate for the active sheet. To be sure that it is calculated for the sheet you need, you should fully qualify the sheet. `LastRow = Sheets("Sales Output").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row`. When stopped on error, move the cursor over the involved cells (`N.Value + P.Value`). Is one of them a string?

Comment: So N.Value or P.Value are of different types probably. Have you inspected their values and types?

Comment: No...the same. When I add option explicit and define N, P and O as range it works. No idea why . Guess it was a declaration issue and that's what confused it?

Comment: Actually, no still getting that error.